# Clear anand-carlsen-2014 up

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I think that the final form should be carlsen-vs-anand-2014, for three reasons.

1. Carlsen is the champion, he should stay first
2. Carlsen-Anand-2014 isn't really clear
3. Anand-vs-Carlsen-2014-wc is really long

Answer (score 1):

I think (2) is fine, and would be clear to anyone who is familiar with the WC cycle or the fact that those two players at some point played for the title.

I agree that (3) is too long, but that doesn't really bother me because it's not as though you often have to type the whole thing in. Another option would be to go for something along the lines of 'World Championship 2014', which then provides the format for any future matches as well.

*EDIT:* Actually, on reflection any format that is used can be reused for future cycles, and I suggest that whatever is chosen that we do so.

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed the tag to [carlsen-anand-2014](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carlsen-anand-2014). The *vs* is unnecessary, as it is common in chess shorthand to refer to a game or a match as "White-Black" (insert player's names).